# Querying array of integers in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Given the following dataset:

```
date        | events
------------+-------------
2019-11-12  | [1, 2, 4, 5]
2019-11-13  | [2, 3, 5]
2019-11-14  | [1, 2]
```

The column `events` as the type `JSON` in BigQuery.

I would like to be able to count rows given a value in `events`

Ideally this is what I would like to achieve:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM mydataset.mytable
WHERE 2 IN events
```

I have looked into Json manipulation in BigQuery's documentation as well as other webpages that discuss that topic and I can't find the solution.

Anyone could help? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `project.mydataset.mytable`
WHERE 2 in UNNEST(events)
```

OR ...

```
#standardSQL
SELECT COUNTIF(2 in UNNEST(events))
FROM `project.mydataset.mytable`
```